# Can I go down to half a life point in Yu-Gi-Oh?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My son plays Yu-Gi-Oh regularly he wants to know can he go down to half a life point?If he has 1 life point,plays solemn judgement, so pays half his life points to negate the spell it would take him down to half a life point.Can he do this?He's asked a few people at his local Yu-Gi-Oh tournaments but nobody was that sure. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello Amanda, Welcome to Board and Card Games. I see that the question I linked above answers your question. Basically it's halved, and then rounded up so... it will be 1LP --> 0.5 LP --> round up --> 1LP ... lol... according to those rulings

Comment: I think this is neither a duplicate (it is, rather, a specific case of a general question asked, which is common on this site).  And this particular case has several extra wrinkles that are not in general applicable (and therefore are specifically not answered in the "marked duplicate") - are you even allowed to do this? - Is there a reason to; are there situations where you don't immediately lose to 0 LP?  My full reasons for considering reopen are https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/recent-yu-gi-oh-questions-reaction-seems-overcritical .

Comment: I don't see how this question is not answered by the one it was marked a duplicate of. In this case the player never goes down to 0 life and they will stay at 1 life because it is rounded up after losing half.

Comment: I suppose the follow up question would be: when paying a half-life point, does the payment get rounded up?